# Dash - Dynamic layout does not propagate resized graph dimensions until window is resized

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, viewport-units

In the sample Dash application below, I am attempting to create a dynamic layout with a variable number of rows and columns. This dynamic grid-style layout will be populated with various graphs that can be modified by dropdowns, etc.

The main issue I have run into thus far pertains to viewport-units and attempting to style the individual graphs appropriately to accommodate the dynamic layout. For example, I am modifying the style of the `dcc.Graph()` components via viewport-units, where the dimensions (e.g. `height` and `width` may be either `35vw` or `23vw` depending on the number of columns). When I change the number of columns from 3 to 2, for example, the `height` and `width` of the `dcc.Graph()` component are clearly changed, however this change is not reflected in the actual rendered layout until the window is physically resized (see the images below the sample code).

How do I force the `dcc.Graph()` components to propagate these changes without having to resize the window?

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
app.config.suppress_callback_exceptions = True

app.layout = html.Div([

    html.Div(className='row', children=[

        html.Div(className='two columns', style={'margin-top': '2%'}, children=[

            html.Div(className='row', style={'margin-top': 30}, children=[

                html.Div(className='six columns', children=[

                    html.H6('Rows'),

                    dcc.Dropdown(
                        id='rows',
                        options=[{
                            'label': i,
                            'value': i
                        } for i in [1,2,3,4]],
                        placeholder='Select number of rows...',
                        clearable=False,
                        value=2
                    ),

                ]),

                html.Div(className='six columns', children=[

                    html.H6('Columns'),

                    dcc.Dropdown(
                        id='columns',
                        options=[{
                            'label': i,
                            'value': i
                        } for i in [1,2,3]],
                        placeholder='Select number of columns...',
                        clearable=False,
                        value=3
                    ),

                ])

            ]),

        ]),

        html.Div(className='ten columns', id='layout-div', style={'border-style': 'solid', 'border-color': 'gray'}, children=[])

    ])

])

@app.callback(
    Output('layout-div', 'children'),
    [Input('rows', 'value'),
    Input('columns', 'value')])
def configure_layout(rows, cols):

    mapping = {1: 'twelve columns', 2: 'six columns', 3: 'four columns', 4: 'three columns'}
    sizing = {1: '40vw', 2: '35vw', 3: '23vw'}

    layout = [html.Div(className='row', children=[

        html.Div(className=mapping[cols], children=[

            dcc.Graph(
                id='test{}'.format(i+1+j*cols),
                config={'displayModeBar': False},
                style={'width': sizing[cols], 'height': sizing[cols]}
            ),

        ]) for i in range(cols)

    ]) for j in range(rows)]

    return layout

#Max layout is 3 X 4
for k in range(1,13):

    @app.callback(
        [Output('test{}'.format(k), 'figure'),
        Output('test{}'.format(k), 'style')],
        [Input('columns', 'value')])
    def create_graph(cols):

        sizing = {1: '40vw', 2: '35vw', 3: '23vw'}

        style = {
            'width': sizing[cols],
            'height': sizing[cols],
        }

        fig = {'data': [], 'layout': {}}

        return [fig, style]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.server.run()
```

Relevant screenshots (Image 1 - page load, Image 2 - change columns to 2):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Might be related to this issue: https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/2769
Using `px` instead of `vw` seems to be working. Probably forcing a redraw of the graph would be the only way to go.

Comment: Are you aware of any way to force the redraw of the graph aside from manually resizing the window? In other words, how would I trigger the redraw?

Comment: `window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));`, ironically it throws an error but works. Unfortunately I don't know of an easy way of calling this line of JS from Dash, except for creating a new component.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how to proceed:

app.py must import:

```
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State, ClientsideFunction
```

let’s include the below Div somewhere in the Dash layout:

```
html.Div(id="output-clientside"),
```

asset folder must include either your own script, or the default script resizing_script.js, which contains:

```
if (!window.dash_clientside) {
    window.dash_clientside = {};
}
window.dash_clientside.clientside = {
    resize: function(value) {
        console.log("resizing..."); // for testing
        setTimeout(function() {
            window.dispatchEvent(new Event("resize"));
            console.log("fired resize");
        }, 500);
    return null;
    },
};
```

Among your callbacks, put this one, without @:

```
app.clientside_callback(
    ClientsideFunction(namespace="clientside", function_name="resize"),
    Output("output-clientside", "children"),
    [Input("yourGraph_ID", "figure")],
)
```

At this point, when you manually resize the window, in your browser, the resize function is triggered.

We aim to achieve the same result, but without manual window resizing. For instance, the trigger could be a className update.

So, we apply the following changes:
Step 1: unchanged

Step 2: unchanged
Step 3: let’s add a “resize2” function inside our javascript file, which takes 2 arguments:

```
if (!window.dash_clientside) {
  window.dash_clientside = {};
}
window.dash_clientside.clientside = {
  resize: function(value) {
    console.log("resizing..."); // for testing
    setTimeout(function() {
      window.dispatchEvent(new Event("resize"));
      console.log("fired resize");
    }, 500);
    return null;
  },

  resize2: function(value1, value2) {
    console.log("resizingV2..."); // for testing
    setTimeout(function() {
       window.dispatchEvent(new Event("resize"));
       console.log("fired resizeV2");
    }, 500);
    return value2; // for testing
  }
};
```

Function “resize2” now takes 2 arguments, one for each Input defined in the below callback. It will return the value of “value2” in the Output, specified in this very same callback. You can set it back to “null”, it’s just to illustrate.

Step4: our callback now becomes:

```
app.clientside_callback(
    ClientsideFunction(namespace="clientside", function_name="resize2"),
    Output("output-clientside", "children"),
    [Input("yourGraph_ID", "figure"), Input("yourDivContainingYourGraph_ID", "className")],
)
```

Finally, you need a button to trigger the event which will change the className of your container.

let’s say your have:

```
daq.ToggleSwitch(
    id='switchClassName',
    label={
        'label':['Option1', 'Option2'],
    },          
    value=False,                                          
),
```

And the following callback:

```
@app.callback(Output("yourDivContainingYourGraph_ID", "className"), 
              [Input("switchClassName","value")]
              )
def updateClassName(value):
    if value==False:
        return "twelve columns"
    else:
        return "nine columns"
```

Now, if you save everything, refresh, everytime you press on your toggleSwitch,it resizes the container, triggers the function, and refreshes the figure.

Given the way it’s done, I assume it must also be possible to run more Javascript functions, the same way, but I didnt check yet.

Hope it will help some

Comment: I was facing the same problem and it worked for me, David!!! Thank you for the great work, David, very appreciate

Answer (score 3):

The behavior looks like a Plotly bug to me.

Here is a possible workaround/short-termin solution.

There is a nice library `visdcc` which allows callbacks with [Javascript](https://github.com/jimmybow/visdcc#3-visdccrun_js-). You can install it via

`pip install visdcc`

Add it to your `div`:

`visdcc.Run_js(id='javascript'),`

and add a callback

```
@app.callback(
    Output('javascript', 'run'),
    [Input('rows', 'value'),
     Input('columns', 'value')])
def resize(_, __): 
    return "console.log('resize'); window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));"
```

Plotly will throw an error in the console after the `resize` event (this also happens when the windows is manually resized) but the plots are shown correctly.

**Full code**

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import visdcc

SIZING = {1: '40vw', 2: '35vw', 3: '23vw'}

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
app.config.suppress_callback_exceptions = True

app.layout = html.Div([
    visdcc.Run_js(id='javascript'),
    html.Div(className='row', children=[

        html.Div(className='two columns', style={'margin-top': '2%'}, children=[

            html.Div(className='row', style={'margin-top': 30}, children=[

                html.Div(className='six columns', children=[

                    html.H6('Rows'),

                    dcc.Dropdown(
                        id='rows',
                        options=[{
                            'label': i,
                            'value': i
                        } for i in [1,2,3,4]],
                        placeholder='Select number of rows...',
                        clearable=False,
                        value=2
                    ),

                ]),

                html.Div(className='six columns', children=[

                    html.H6('Columns'),

                    dcc.Dropdown(
                        id='columns',
                        options=[{
                            'label': i,
                            'value': i
                        } for i in [1,2,3]],
                        placeholder='Select number of columns...',
                        clearable=False,
                        value=3
                    ),

                ])

            ]),

        ]),

        html.Div(className='ten columns', id='layout-div', style={'border-style': 'solid', 'border-color': 'gray'}, children=[])

    ])

])


@app.callback(
    Output('layout-div', 'children'),
    [Input('rows', 'value'),
    Input('columns', 'value')])
def configure_layout(rows, cols):

    mapping = {1: 'twelve columns', 2: 'six columns', 3: 'four columns', 4: 'three columns'}

    layout = [html.Div(className='row', children=[

        html.Div(className=mapping[cols], style={'width': SIZING[cols], 'height': SIZING[cols]}, children=[

            dcc.Graph(
                id='test{}'.format(i+1+j*cols),
                config={'displayModeBar': False},
                style={'width': SIZING[cols], 'height': SIZING[cols]}
            ),

        ]) for i in range(cols)

    ]) for j in range(rows)]
    return layout

@app.callback(
    Output('javascript', 'run'),
    [Input('rows', 'value'),
     Input('columns', 'value')])
def resize(_, __): 
    return "console.log('resize'); window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));"


#Max layout is 3 X 4
for k in range(1,13):

    @app.callback(
        [Output('test{}'.format(k), 'figure'),
         Output('test{}'.format(k), 'style')],
        [Input('columns', 'value')])
    def create_graph(cols):

        style = {
            'width': SIZING[cols],
            'height': SIZING[cols],
        }

        fig = {'data': [], 'layout': {}}
        return [fig, style]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.server.run()
```

Comment: This is an excellent workaround for the time being! I appreciate the thorough answer. I can live with the errors printing to the console for now, as my end-users likely don't know how to access the Developer Tools anyway.

Comment: With the implementation of `ClientsideFunction` in `Dash`, the answer by @David22 is the more direct solution to this issue. The workaround you provided here was more than sufficient prior to the new solution. Thank you again!